# Clojure: Separating a particular element from a nested list

Tags: clojure, tree, nested-lists

I'm currently working on lists. I'm working on a function at the moment which uses recursion to iterate through the nested-list structure I have created (or any). In an attempt to separate the numbers from the other elements in this structure. By separate I mean add them to an empty list and have them as the function output.

For example:

```
(def my-tree   
'(3 (apple) -2 ( 50 orange ) 9 banana))

(defn function [my-tree]  
  if list is empty then return nil.

if not then search through the list and append all numbers to an empty list.

)

user => (function my-tree)  
(3 -2 50 9)
```

Comment: Do you know about recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
(def my-tree
  '(3 (apple) -2 ( 50 orange ) 9 banana))

(def flat-tree (flatten my-tree))

(def nums (filter number? flat-tree))
(def syms (filter symbol? flat-tree))

flat-tree => (3 apple -2 50 orange 9 banana)
nums => (3 -2 50 9)
syms => (apple orange banana)
```

You should save a bookmark [to The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) and always keep a browser tab open to it.  Study the functions and practice them all.  Enjoy!

Comment: Much appreciated Alan. The flatten function is exactly what I needed. I also found juxt too which would help. I realise it was a little hasty not reading the clojure docs before coming here, though I'm still grateful you took the time to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
(defn tree->nums [tree]
    (->> tree flatten (filter number?))

(tree->nums my-tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of data manipulation in Clojure has [been a problem long enough](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/clojures-missing-piece.html) that [someone much smarter than I](http://nathanmarz.com/) wrote a very popular library to easily and efficiently solve this kind of problem (and **much much more**).

Here's how to solve this with specter:

```
user> (def my-tree   
        '(3 (apple) -2 ( 50 orange ) 9 banana))
#'user/my-tree
user> (use 'com.rpl.specter)
nil

user> (select (walker number?) my-tree)
[3 -2 50 9]
```

Specter was first released a couple of years ago and has recently gained traction and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers so far has used recursion, which you mention in your question, I'll chime in with a recursive solution.

```
(def my-tree
  '(3 (apple) -2 ( 50 orange ) 9 banana))

(defn tree-nums-helper
  [acc tree]
  (cond
    ;; If tree is a collection, reduce tree-nums-helper over it using the
    ;; current acc as the initial value.
    (coll? tree) (reduce tree-nums-helper acc tree)

    ;; So, tree is not a collection, it's a leaf.
    ;; If it's a number, add it to the accumulator.
    (number? tree) (conj acc tree)

    ;; Else, just return the accumulator untouched.
    :else acc))

(defn tree-nums
  "Takes a tree and returns a vector of the numbers it contains
   in depth first order."
  [tree]
  ;; Just calls the helper with an empty accumulator.
  (tree-nums-helper [] tree))


(tree-nums my-tree) ;=> [3 -2 50 9]
```

If you want to re-use the recursive tree walk logic to find other things than numbers, you can write a function that takes a predicate (a function that returns a boolean) and returns a tree-walker.

```
;; dfs = depth first search

(defn dfs-factory [pred]
  ;; You can name anonymous functions so that you can recursively
  ;; refer to them from within themselves
  (fn dfs
    ([tree]
     (dfs [] tree))

    ;; Instead of having a helper fn, here we have an extra arity.
    ([acc tree]
     (cond
       (coll? tree) (reduce dfs acc tree)
       (pred tree) (conj acc tree)
       :else acc))))

(def tree-nums
  (dfs-factory number?))

(tree-nums my-tree) ;=> [3 -2 50 9]

(def tree-syms
  (dfs-factory symbol?))

(tree-syms my-tree) ;=> [apple orange banana]
```